# CommentViewRow comment text weird spacing behavior...?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to make an adaptive `CommentViewRow` for a social app where the whole comment text can be displayed within the row.

So far I am achieving this but I have **3 issues**:

1 When the comment-text is short it is being centred within the row even when I specify ".alignment: .leading" in the `VStack`.

2 When the comment-text uses more than one line there is a mysterious padding between the user's profile picture & the comment-text?? see image below.

3 I am not sure if my `.frame` modifier is the best way to achieve what I am doing, it seems mickey-mouse, I was reading about .frame(`idealWith`, `idealHeight`, etc..) and not sure if that would help.

Any idea on how I can fix this so that each `CommentViewRow` displays like your average social-media comment view??

Thank you!

[image]

```
struct CommentViewRow: View {    
    var comment: Comment
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack { 
            KFImage("profilePicture")
           
            // COMMENT
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("**\(comment.username)** \(comment.comment)")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 310) 
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                
                Text(comment.createdAt.timeAgoDisplay())
                    .bold()
                    .font(.caption)     
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1st option: If you really need that view to be `310` wide

You can change `.frame(width: 310)` to `.frame(width: 310, alignment: .leading)`

##### 2nd option: Let the view adjust itself based on content, you just need to specify the alignment (`.leading` in this case)

```
struct CommentViewRow: View {
    var comment: Comment
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            KFImage("profilePicture")

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("**\(comment.username)** \(comment.comment)")
                    .font(.caption)

                Text(comment.createdAt.timeAgoDisplay())
                    .font(.caption.bold())
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
        .padding([.horizontal], 10)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, get rid of the frame:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var comment = "Thjfhg jhfgjhdfg jdfhgj  dfhdfsjjdfgh djdshfg hjdfgjfdh ghjkf gdhjdfgh jkh fjg dfjkhgj dfglkhdfsg"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("\(comment)")
                    .font(.caption)
                
                Text("3 minutes ago")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
    }
}
```